# How to simplify: $C_{t} = r[a_{t} + \frac{1}{1+r} * \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{1+r})^j * E(w_{t+j})]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

I have to find C_t (Optimal Consumption for each period). Thank you!

$$C_{t} = r[a_{t} + \frac{1}{1+r} * \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{1+r})^j * E(w_{t+j})]$$

Where,

$$w_{t+j} = \begin{cases} w + \Delta &, j=0,2,4... \\
                     w - (1+r)*\Delta &, j=1,3,5....\end{cases}$$

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you can help. I have to simplify this equation and find optimal consumption for each period t.

Comment: I used the average of the two values of w and plugged it in instead of E(W) but I am not sure if that's a correct way to do it.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I got $$C_{t} = ra_{t} + w - (r\Delta)/(2)$$

Comment: Is $\omega_{t+j}$ linked to $W$? And dit $E(.)$ stand for expectation? Is $\omega_{t+j}$ a random variable?

Comment: @AbdoulHaki Yes, I am sorry. w is a wage for each period. E is an expectation. In even periods wage increases by delta, and in odd periods the wage decreases by (1+r)*delta. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Comment: You meant $w_j = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
w_{j-1} + \Delta & j = 0, 2, 4,\dots\\
w_{j-1} - (1+r)*\Delta & j = 1, 3, 5,\dots\\
\end{array}\right.$ ?

Comment: @AbdoulHaki w stays the same in this case, it is not changing.

Comment: There is still much unclear. Is left-hand side of last line $w_j$? Is $w$ in right-hand side of this line some constant or previous value like in Abdoul comment? Is $t$ non-negative integer? If $E(w_{t+j})$ is expected value, then what are averaging conditions?

Comment: w stays the same for all periods j. The equation is a general case where w can change in each period. But for this problem, the assumption is that if j is 0,2,4.. wage increases by delta and if j is 1,3,5... wage decreases by -(1+r)*delta.

Comment: When $w_j$ is constant I am getting $C_t = r*a + w$. But if it is changing do I have to plug the weighted average of w into the equation?  $1/2 *(w+\Delta) + 1/2*(w-(1+r)*\Delta)$

Comment: As I understand, there is some infinite sequence $w_j$ such that $w_j=w_0=w+\Delta$ for even $j$ and $w_j=w_1=w-(1+r)\Delta$ for odd $j$. There is non-negative integer index $t$. Then sequence $C_t$ is defined by $C_t=r\left(a_t+\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+r)^{j+1}} E(w_{t+j})\right)$. $w_{t+j}$ is not random variable it is just one of sequence $w_j$ terms. Then what is $E(w_{t+j})$? If $w_{t+j}$ is random variable, then what is source of this randomness?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu In this case $w_{t+j}$ is not random since it just alternates between two values. The expected value was given in the initial problem. Since there is no randomness is it possible to just find the infinite sum in some way? When w is constant in each period, I just pull it out of the sum but now it changes in each period.

Comment: If sum is really $S=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+r)^{j+1}} w_{t+j}$ then it can be found. First step: divide sum into even $j=2m$ and odd $j=2n+1$. $S=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+r)^{2m+1}} w_{t+2m}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+r)^{2n+2}} w_{t+2n+1}$. Second step: Use $w_{t+2m}=w_t$ and factor out. $S=\frac{w_t}{1+r} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+r)^{2m}}+\frac{w_{t+1}}{(1+r)^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+r)^{2n}}$. Third step: use infinite geometric sequence sum and factor out. $S=\left(\frac{w_t}{1+r} + \frac{w_{t+1}}{(1+r)^2}\right) \frac{(1+r)^2}{(1+r)^2-1}$.

Comment: Result for $S$ can be written as $S=S_0$ for even $t$ and $S=S_1$ for odd $t$, where $S_0$ is value at $t=0$ and $S_1$ is value at $t=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $\omega$ is not a random variable but just a sequence of real value and answer you question.
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+r)^j} * E(w_{t+j}) &= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+r)^j}\left[(\omega) +(\omega - (1+r)\Delta) + (\omega+\Delta) + (\omega - (1+r)\Delta)  + \dots \right]\\
&= \omega + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+r)^{2j-1}}\left[\omega - (1+r)\Delta\right] + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+r)^{2j}}\left[\omega+\Delta\right]\\
&= \omega + \frac{\omega(1+r)}{(1+r)^2-1} - \frac{\Delta(1+r)^2}{(1+r)^2-1} + \frac{\omega+\Delta}{(1+r)^2-1}\\
&=\frac{\omega(1+r) + (\omega+\Delta)(1+r)^2 + \Delta}{(1+r)^2 - 1}
\end{align}
Then, you get
\begin{align}
C_t = r\left[a_t + \frac{\omega + (\omega+\Delta)(1+r) + \frac{\Delta}{1+r}}{(1+r)^2 - 1}\right]
\end{align}